# How to get the XML data from different server?

Tags: php, xml, soap

At present i am working on flight portal using PHP, SOAP , XML. We have taken the flight API from some 'X' provider. In that API they have given a sample file which contains international flight availability search Code. The code in that file is as below.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script language="Javascript">
function submit_search()
{       
    window.document.forms[0].action="http://URL/Avalability";   
    window.document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<form method="post">
    XML Request:    <input type="text" name="xmlRequest" id="fromcity" value="XML CODE FOR FLIGHT AVAILABILITY" />

    <input type="button" name="SUBMIT" value="submit" onClick="submit_search();"/>

</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

By executing the above code I am getting the Flight results in the other server . Now i want to get back that result into my file. How can we do that.

Answer (score 0):

for your requirement you need to use ajax concept for getting the contents of those flight details from the server

this following url may helps you in this regard

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Development/functionloadstheXMLdocumentfromthespecifiedURL.htm

i hope it will provides a brief way to your solution

any comments are appreciated

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply. Just now i went through your link. I think it will surely help me. I will just check it practically and let you know. Once again thanku very much.

Comment: Hi krishna what i understand from that link is we can get the XML from a particular URL and print that in our own design. But here first i want to send some details To that URL like Location1,Location2,Date of journey,Date of return. then according to our details a xml date will generate. Now we want to get those data to our file.How to do that..?

Comment: Hope you understand telugu. Naku konni doubts vunnay sir. Miru naku help ceyagalara...?? na email id sree.prasad1254@gmail.com  Please ping me there sir.

Comment: similarly you have to do same thing for second requirement.because requirement is same for both.what i mean is in your first requirement you need to send some details to server then based on the results you need to send second query to server.so in your first requiement you get one value then you get no of record based on the first value

Comment: this forum is for us to clarify all our doubts.... may be anyone of here may give better solution than me.so post all your doubts here deffinitely you will get better solution for all your problems